# Using 'max' and 'len' to properly format the 10th item of a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, max, string-length

```
    for i, items in enumerate(zip(member_names, scores)):
        if i < 10:
            if i == 9:
                msg += "{:<1}. {:<{names_len}} <{:,}>\n".format(i + 1, *items, names_len=len(max(member_names, key=len)) - 1)
                continue
            msg += "{:<1}. {:<{names_len}} <{:,}>\n".format(i + 1, *items, names_len=len(max(member_names, key=len)))
```

Here's an example output:

```
1. xxxx#1598         <12,704>
2. xxxxxxxxxxxx#2390 <7,151>
3. xxxxx#4966        <5,859>
4. xxxx#3562         <3,051>
5. xxxxxxx#6967      <2,831>
6. xxxxx#4643        <2,073>
7. xxxxx#2006        <1,833>
8. xxxx#4720         <1,679>
9. xxxx#8049         <1,651>
10. xxxxxxxxxxxx#8514 <1,614>
```

`member_names` is a list with a few dozen items in it. My two issues:

1. I can't get it to properly account for the fact that the 10th item in the list will need one less space of indention.
2. Being such, as you can see, the 10th item does not extend the indention an extra character while using `names_len`.

Can anyone help with this? I'm fairly new and have been stumped on this for quite a while.

Comment: If you are using recent python you can also use fstrings instead of format, I find it more readable

Answer (score 1):

I would try to unclutter the whole thing a bit. Let's find out the maximum length ahead of time (instead of having to determine it once per loop); same with the maximum index number:

```
num_items = len(str(len(member_names)))
max_length = len(max(member_names, key=len))
for i, items in enumerate(zip(member_names, scores)):
    msg += "{:>{n}}. {:<{m}} <{:,}>\n".format(i + 1, n=num_items, *items, m=max_length)
```

(I hope this works as is - can't test it without access to your data)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply ident the lower numbers by right-aligning them:

```
member_names = [f"name_{i}" for i in range(14)]
scores = [3**i for i in range(14)]

maxlen = len(max(member_names, key=len)) # calculate only once
msg = ""
for i, items in enumerate(zip(member_names, scores)):
    msg += "{:>2}. {:<{ml}} <{:,}>\n".format(i + 1, *items,ml=maxlen)

print(msg)
```

Output:

```
 1. name_0  <1>
 2. name_1  <3>
 3. name_2  <9>
 4. name_3  <27>
 5. name_4  <81>
 6. name_5  <243>
 7. name_6  <729>
 8. name_7  <2,187>
 9. name_8  <6,561>
10. name_9  <19,683>
11. name_10 <59,049>
12. name_11 <177,147>
13. name_12 <531,441>
14. name_13 <1,594,323>
```

See [Tim Pietzckers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52924985/7505395) for a more flexible approach that would allow >99 highscores and still be aligned.

Answer (score -1):

`len()`already returns the number of items in a list. ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len))
`max()` returns the highest number. ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max))

So `len(max())` returns 1, as it looks for the highest number in the list (10) and then calls len(10), which == 1

Comment: This is incorrect. `len(max(member_names, key=len))` returns the length of the longest string in `member_names`. It does so by first finding the longest string (`max()` of `member_names` according to length), and then determining its length.